# selecting by nth child in css3

Tags: html, css

How to add different border color for each anchor tag? (In sass preferably)

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-border"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-border"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-border"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-border"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-border"></i></a>
</div>

css that not working:

.fa-border{
  &:nth-child(1){
    border: 1px solid #d12883;     
  }
  &:nth-child(2){
    border: 1px solid #39a835;     
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example the .fa-border elements are not childs of
the same parent.

Try:

```
.container a:nth-child(1) .fa-border {
    border: 1px solid #d12883;
} 
.container a:nth-child(2) .fa-border {
    border: 1px solid #39a835;
}
```

Comment: its gives nth-child(1) color to every child

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

For Sass:

```
a {
  &:nth-child(1) .fa-border {
    border: 1px solid #d12883;     
  }
  &:nth-child(2) .fa-border {
    border: 1px solid #39a835;     
  }  
}
```

For CSS3:

```
a:nth-child(1) .fa-border {
    border: 1px solid #d12883;  
}

a:nth-child(2) .fa-border {
  border: 1px solid #39a835;     
}
```

Comment: @jeprubio That's because it's in Sass. I've updated it with the CSS3 solution